# Как вывести переменную из функции

Tags: скрипт, php, функции

Здравствуйте! Мне дальше в коде нужно использовать переменную $name, как ее вывести из функции? И как записывать во внешнем файле? Спасибо.

```
function LoadFoto($foto){
$type = $foto['type'];
$name = $foto['name'];
$uploaddir = "avatars/";
$name = md5(microtime()).".".substr($type, strlen("image/"));
if(move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$name)) 
{
return true; 
}
else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return $name вместо return true
или $name = functionName($type), и во внешней программе тоже вызывать эту функцию

Answer (score 2):

Вар. 1 - передавать её в функцию по ссылке:

```
$theName = '';
$theFoto = {...};
$result = LoadFoto( $theFoto, $theName);
// используем уставновленное из функции значение $theName
...
function LoadFoto( $foto, &$name){
    ...
    $name = 'trololo';
    return TRUE;
}
```

Вар. 2 - возвращать объект или массив:

```
$response = LoadFoto( $foto);
if( $response['result']) {
    echo $response['name'];
}
...
function LoadFoto($foto){
    ...
    return array( 'result'=>TRUE, 'name'=>$name);
}
```